# Can a thread be reused to run variadic functions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread, variadic-templates

I am trying to create a boost thread in C++ that can be reused to run a variety of functions that can have different number and type of args.

Can this be done with C++11x variadics?

In my use case I do not need a queue (if the thread is busy then the method would simply fail), but if it is required to implement this "unify" functionality I would reluctantly do so.

I do not understand how to handle the unify with bind or lambda so that one thread can call different functions that each have their own and different quantities and types of args.

I have roughly the following in mind:

```
class WorkThread
{
public:
   WorkThread()
       {
       // create thread and bind runner to thread
       }

   ~WorkThread()
       {
       // tell runner to exit and wait and reap the thread
       }

   template<typename F,typename ... Arguments>
   void doWork(F func, Arguments... args)
       {
       if already busy
           return false;
       // set indication to runner that there is new work
       // here: how to pass f and args to runner?
       }

private:
   void runner()
        {
        while ( ! time to quit )
            {
            wait for work
            // here: how to get f and args from doWork? do I really need a queue? could wait on a variadic signal maybe?
            f(args);
            }
        }

   boost::thread* m_thread;
};

class ThreadPool
{
public:
    template<typename F, typename ... Arguments>
    bool   doWork(F func,Arguments... args)
          {
          const int i = findAvailableWorkThread();
          m_thread[i].doWork(f,args);
          }
private:
   // a pool of work threads m_thread;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be lots of existing questions showing how to do this.

The canonical C++11 way to represent an arbitrary function object is `std::function<void()>`, so you want a shared object of that type, called `m_job` in the code below, which should be protected by a mutex, and you assign new jobs to it when it's not already set:

```
template<typename F,typename ... Arguments>
bool doWork(F func, Arguments&&... args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m_job_mutex);
    if (m_job)
        return false;
    m_job = std::bind(func, std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
    m_job_cond.notify_one();  
    return true;   
}
```

This uses `std::bind` to turn a function object and its arguments into a function object taking no arguments. The callable object returned by `std::bind` stores a copy of `func` and each argument, and when invoked it calls `func(args...)`

Then the worker just does:

```
void runner()
{
    while ( ! time to quit )
    {
        std::function<void()> job;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m_job_mutex);
            while (!m_job)
                m_job_cond.wait(l);
            swap(job, m_job);
        }
        job();
    }
}
```

This code isn't thread-safe:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Arguments>
    bool   doWork(F func,Arguments... args)
    {
        const int i = findAvailableWorkThread();
        m_thread[i].doWork(f,args);
    }
```

After `findAvailableWorkThread` returns, that thread could become busy, so the next line will fail. You should check for availability and pass the new job in a single operation, e.g.

```
template<typename F, typename ... Arguments>
    bool   doWork(F func,Arguments... args)
    {
        for (auto& t : m_thread)
            if (t.doWork(f,args))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unify all your functions to one signature by either using `boost::bind` or C++11 `lambda`. So you will have a thread with loop function and inside that loop you will extract function you want to execute.
To achieve it you can use `boost::lockfree::queue<boost::function<void()>>`, for example.

Just as an example of the idea you can use the following:

```
class TaskLoop
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> Task_t;
public:
    TaskLoop():
        m_IsDone(false)
    {
        m_spThread.reset(new std::thread(&TaskLoop::_run, this));
    }
    ~TaskLoop()
    {
        Task_t task = [this](){m_IsDone = true;};
        postTask(task);
        m_spThread->join();
    }
    void postTask(const Task_t& Msg)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_Mutex);
        m_Tasks.push(Msg);
    }
    void wait() 
    {
        while(!m_Tasks.empty());
    }
private:
    bool m_IsDone;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread> m_spThread; 
    std::mutex m_Mutex;
    std::queue<Task_t> m_Tasks;
private:
    void _run()
    {
        while(!m_IsDone)
        {
            Task_t task;
            m_Mutex.lock();
            if(!m_Tasks.empty())
            {
                task = m_Tasks.front();
                m_Tasks.pop();
            }
            m_Mutex.unlock();
            if(task)
                task();
        }
    }
};

void foo(const std::string& first, int second)
{
    std::cout << first << second << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TaskLoop loop;
    loop.postTask([]{foo("task", 0);});
    loop.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Example doesn't use concurrent queue and quite simple, so you need to replace queue and adapt it to your requirements

Comment: not really: `boost::function` does not meet the requirements for `boost::lockfree::queue`

Comment: How would you stuff the function, its return type and the arg pack into the queue? I have seen mention of using a tuple for this, so is the suggestion then that the queue hold the arg pack as a tuple? I don't know how to do that. Can it be shown?

Answer (score 1):

As you are already using boost, see the thread pool class at http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes which uses Boost.Asio to queue work functions without locking.

Answer (score 0):

// here is what I have so far that seems to work....

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>

#include <queue>
#include <atomic>

class ThreadWorker
    {
    public:
        typedef boost::function<void()> Task_t;
        typedef std::unique_ptr<boost::thread>  UniqueThreadPtr_t;

        ThreadWorker()
            : m_timeToQuit(false)
            {
            m_spThread = UniqueThreadPtr_t( new boost::thread(std::bind(&ThreadWorker::runner, this)));
            }

        virtual ~ThreadWorker()
            {
            quit();
            }

        void quit()
            {
            Task_t task = [this]() { m_timeToQuit = true; };
            enqueue(task);
            m_spThread->join();
            }

        template<typename F,typename ...Args>
        void enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args)
            {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_jobMutex);
            m_Tasks.push(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f),std::forward<Args>(args)...));
            m_newJob.notify_one();
            }

    private:
        std::atomic<bool>       m_timeToQuit;
        UniqueThreadPtr_t       m_spThread;
        mutable boost::mutex    m_jobMutex;
        std::queue<Task_t>      m_Tasks;
        boost::condition        m_newJob;

    private:
        void runner()
            {
            while ( ! m_timeToQuit )
                {
                Task_t task;
                    {
                    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_jobMutex);
                    while ( ! task )
                        {
                        if ( m_timeToQuit )
                            {
                            break;
                            }
                        if ( m_Tasks.empty() )
                            {
                            m_newJob.wait(lock);
                            }
                        task = m_Tasks.front();
                        m_Tasks.pop();
                        }
                    }
                if (task)
                    {
                    task();
                    }
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: How can I add ability to wait for a result? I need a new version of enqueue with a template return type?

Comment: Maybe something like:`code` template<typename F,typename ...Args,typename R=typename std::result_of<F(Args&&...)>::type>
            auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<R>{...}  but then how to define the queue of tasks

Comment: Can someone show how to chenage the queue and the enqueue to deal with futures? I cannot figure it out.